# Referencing enumerated observations in proof

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, enumerate

I am writing a rather complicated proof (graph theory/algorithmics), which contains a number of listed observations that are going to be referenced later in the course of the proof. The observations are related to the proof directly, so the list cannot be taken out as an observation before the proof.

```
\begin{proof}
     (...)
     In this case the colors look like this:XX.
     (...)
     Observe that:
     \begin{enumerate}
          \item White is white
          \item Black is black
     \end{enumerate}
     (...)
     By the second observation, we know that black is not green.
     (...)
\end{proof}
```

Is there any "right" way to do it?
I have browsed through the other similar questions suggested by the system here and all of them seem to just show how to adjust how labels/references to enumerated items are presented.

I would most preferably like to know if there is any "conventional" way to do this. Drop the enumerate somehow completely? Embed it in some kind of Observation environment and reference the items as sub-observations?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Is this a TeX/LaTeX question?

Comment: @egreg Good point - I actually see it as a question halfways between LaTeX and general writing style. I mostly know how I want my text to look like, and would not be surprised if somebody came up with some kind of his writing scheme and custom LaTeX environment/macros handling such a case - therefore I posted it here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking whether the enumerate list items can be cross-referenced, then it is possible using the `enumerate` package. See the below example:

```
\begin{proof}
     (...)
     In this case the colors look like this:XX.
     (...)
     Observe that:
     \begin{enumerate}
          \item\label{obs:1} White is white
          \item\label{obs:2} Black is black
     \end{enumerate}
     (...)
     By observation~\ref{obs:2}, we know that black is not green.
     (...)
\end{proof}
```

See the labels `obs:1` and `obs:2` defined inside the enumerate and called using `\ref` command.

Comment: The `enumerate` package is not needed.

Comment: Thanks, although unfortunately that's not exactly what I meant. Many other questions/answers already presented how to reference enumerate items. I am more interested in how this is supposed to be done in general - is referencing the enumerate elements a good practice or am I supposed to embed an observation environment in the proof? Or maybe is there another commonly used and recommended solution?